# Magento 1.x to 2.x "Remove outdated and redundant data"

Tags: magento2, database, magento-1, magento2-migration-tool

Before data migration, the Magento 2 migration guide suggests...

> Remove outdated and redundant data from your Magento 1 database (for
>   example, you could remove logs, order quotes, recently viewed or
>   compared products, visitors, event-specific categories, promotional
>   rules, and so on)

Does anyone have a reference to the specific tables that can be cleaned up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes magento suggest we need  to remove all log tables and unused quotes from old database. for that you can run following query

```
TRUNCATE dataflow_batch_export;
TRUNCATE dataflow_batch_import;
TRUNCATE log_customer;
TRUNCATE log_quote;
TRUNCATE log_summary;
TRUNCATE log_summary_type;
TRUNCATE log_url;
TRUNCATE log_url_info;
TRUNCATE log_visitor;
TRUNCATE log_visitor_info;
TRUNCATE log_visitor_online;
TRUNCATE report_viewed_product_index;
TRUNCATE report_compared_product_index;
TRUNCATE report_event;
TRUNCATE index_event;
DELETE FROM sales_flat_quote WHERE is_active = 1;
```

Now you can proceed to migration. 
Thanks.

Comment: So are those operations also safe to periodically on a production Magento database to keep size in check?

Comment: Actually sales quote data we should not remove when site is in production mode. but log tables you can truncate to reduce size of database. and improve performance. 
But in production mode it should be done after taking one secure backup.

Comment: TRUNCATE index_event;  foreign key constraint